# Issue with 24hour date format

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert Date object in string using DateFormatter but I am getting some weird behavior. I have a timestamp value (1513356296) which I want to convert in 24hour format along with date and timeZone (My current is -0800). Here is my code:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(1513356296))
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -(8*3600))
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
```

I am expecting a result value of `2017-12-15T08:44:56-0800` but I am getting `2017-12-15T8:44:56-0800`. Everything is same except the hour value. The hour value is 8 instead of 08.

This is not happing with all the test, it happened in only one device and rest are fine.

I also tried by checking if hour value changes if I change device time setting to 12hour format from 24hour format to see what I get for HH and it was always giving me 08 in my case. Only one user was facing this issue.

What's wrong with my code? or is there something wrong with HH I am using?

Comment: Set the locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html which is linked in [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) documentation. Also, you can use [ISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter) directly.

Comment: And you should set your timezone to UTC (zero seconds from GMT) instead of manually setting an offset.